# document.body.append(document.createElement('p').innerHTML="this is p") behaving differently if I give them in separate statements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I am trying to add HTML elements dynamically using DOM manipulation. I tried two ways but got different outputs. Can someone explain why?

```
        document.body.append(document.createElement('p').innerHTML="this is p");
        document.body.append(document.createElement('p').innerHTML="this is another p");
        var abc = document.createElement('p');
        abc.innerHTML = 'this is p';
        document.body.append(abc);
        var xyz = document.createElement('p');
        xyz.innerHTML = 'this is another p';
        document.body.append(xyz);
```

The output I got is

this is pthis is another p

this is p

this is another p

[image]
Why is it not giving spaces? Why different output if both ways are same?

Answer (score 1):

It seem's two different output because

```
document.body.append(document.createElement('p').innerHTML="this is p");
```

you have still not created the element properly and before that assigned the value so javascript understand that append simple string and not created the P tag.

using this approach first you have created the p element and assign to variable and then you have appended to body.

```
var abc = document.createElement('p');
abc.innerHTML = 'this is p';
document.body.append(abc);
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

[append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) doesn't return anything, and `document.body.append(document.createElement('p').innerHTML="this is p");` creates only a textnode inside the arguments, as the passed argument is evaluated to the string the assignment returns. `p` element exists only at the time the argument is evaluated, and the paragraph is never appended to `body`.

A single-liner would use `appendChild`:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('p')).innerHTML = "this is p";
```